# how do i randomly assign accounts into 3 groups that is similar by way of average spend and frequency of spend

Tags: r, dplyr, random

I have a some sample sales transactions by accounts, and would like to do a test and learn on 3 groups. I'd like the assign 3 groups to all the unique account ids and have them to be as similar as possible so the trial can be without selection bias. The bias could be in by frequency of transaction, average spend, and total spend.

I was considering using a quantile function i.e. mutate ntile for 5 bins based on sale_amount then subsequently group by and sample_n.

If i'm on the right track, is there an elegant way to parameterize the number of groups into a function and do this elegantly?

Appreciate your help with your methods in R.

```
# Load required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


# Set the start and end dates
start_date <- as.Date("2023-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2023-03-31")

# Number of accounts
num_accounts <- 90


# Function to generate random transactions and sale amounts for each day
generate_random_transactions <- function(date) {
  num_transactions <- sample(1:5, 1)  # Random number of transactions per day (1 to 5)
  sale_amounts <- runif(num_transactions, min = 10, max = 500)  # Random sale amount between 10 and 500
  transactions <- data.frame(date = date, sale_amount = sale_amounts)
  return(transactions)
}
set,seed(1)
# Generate transactions for each day within the specified date range for all accounts
all_transactions <- lapply(seq(start_date, end_date, by = "day"), generate_random_transactions)
all_transactions <- do.call(rbind, all_transactions) %>% tibble

# Assign random account numbers to each transaction
all_transactions$id <- 
  sample(1:num_accounts, nrow(all_transactions), replace = TRUE)

# Display the first few rows of the resulting transactions
all_transactions
```

```
all_transactions %>% 
  mutate(quantile = ntile(sale_amount,5)) %>% 
  group_by(quantile) %>% 
  summarise(acct_n=n_distinct(id),
            freq_n = n(),
            amt_mean=mean(sale_amount),
            amt_min=min(sale_amount),
            amt_max=max(sale_amount))
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  quantile acct_n freq_n amt_mean amt_min amt_max
     <int>  <int>  <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1        1     40     52     71.8    10.7    128.
2        2     39     52    178.    130.     230.
3        3     40     52    281.    233.     331.
4        4     37     52    376.    332.     420.
5        5     41     51    462.    421.     499.
```

Comment: You might look at the `tidymodels` package, which is built to provide good workflows for modeling and machine learning. e.g. https://www.tidymodels.org/start/recipes/#data-split and https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/initial_split.html

Answer (score 0):

So after reading up randomised [complete block design](http://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Ehalina/603/603RCBD.pdf), i've hacked a code below to ensure homogeneity across all 3 groups assigned. Please call out if you see below is incorrect.

```
#generate acct features by average order value, frequency, and total spend categorised as variation
acct_stats <- 
  all_transactions %>% 
  group_by(id,date) %>% 
  mutate(sale_amount = sum(sale_amount)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(sale_aov_perday=mean(sale_amount),
         sale_freq_tx = n(),
         sale_sum = sum(sale_amount)) %>% 
  mutate(quantile_aov = ntile(sale_aov_perday,3), 
         quantile_freq = ntile(sale_aov_perday,3),
         quantile_sum = ntile(sale_sum,3),
         variation = paste0(quantile_aov,quantile_freq,quantile_sum))
 
# A tibble: 4,936 × 8
       id sale_aov_perday sale_freq_tx sale_sum quantile_aov quantile_freq quantile_sum variation
    <int>           <dbl>        <int>    <dbl>        <int>         <int>        <int> <chr>    
  1     1           281.             4   1124.             2             2            2 222      
  2     2           181.             4    724.             1             1            1 111      
  3     3           474.             1    474.             3             3            1 331      
  4     4           184.             4    734.             1             1            1 111      
  5     5           266.             4   1066.             2             2            2 222      
  6     6           302.             5   1509.             3             3            3 333      
  7     7           241.             6   1449.             2             2            3 223      
  8     8           307.            10   3072.             3             3            3 333      
  9     9           255.             5   1277.             2             2            2 222
```

From there, i can now assign equal number of customers into the 3 groups stratified by the 3 variations equally as below

```
#randomised complete block assignment
# Generate random assignment of groups stratified by "quantile_all"
num_groups <- 3

set.seed(1) # Setting seed for reproducibility
group_assignment <- 
  acct_stats %>%
  select(id, variation) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(variation) %>% 
  sample_frac(1) %>%  # Randomly shuffle the data
  mutate(grp = rep(1:num_groups, length.out = n())) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(id,grp)

# Merge the group assignment back to acct stats data
acct_stats <- 
  acct_stats %>%
  left_join(group_assignment, by = "id")
```

final check on the group assignment being as equal as possible

```
acct_stats %>% 
  inner_join(all_transactions) %>% 
  group_by(variation,grp) %>% 
  summarise(acct_n=n_distinct(id),
            freq_n = n(),
            amt_sum = sum(sale_amount),
            amt_mean=mean(sale_amount),
            amt_median=median(sale_amount),
            amt_min=min(sale_amount),
            amt_max=max(sale_amount)) %>% 
  print(n=30)

# A tibble: 27 × 9
# Groups:   variation [9]
   variation   grp acct_n freq_n amt_sum amt_mean amt_median amt_min amt_max
   <chr>     <int>  <int>  <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 111           1    343   1008 159166.     158.       134.    10.2    494.
 2 111           2    343    966 150823.     156.       133.    10.0    500.
 3 111           3    343    957 147049.     154.       130.    10.1    499.
 4 112           1    174    909 173769.     191.       173.    10.6    499.
 5 112           2    173    891 175384.     197.       176.    10.4    498.
 6 112           3    173    920 177859.     193.       178.    11.2    500.
 7 113           1     33    267  54395.     204.       179.    10.7    493.
 8 113           2     32    244  50897.     209.       193.    10.1    499.
 9 113           3     32    241  48684.     202.       181.    13.0    498.
10 221           1    110    247  62846.     254.       241.    14.8    499.
11 221           2    110    259  64734.     250.       244.    10.3    499.
12 221           3    109    252  64154.     255.       254.    10.3    494.
13 222           1    222    898 233261.     260.       256.    10.4    499.
14 222           2    222    905 232378.     257.       258.    10.1    498.
15 222           3    222    920 238035.     259.       257.    10.5    498.
16 223           1    217   1511 384751.     255.       255.    10.4    500.
17 223           2    217   1472 379883.     258.       255.    10.3    500.
18 223           3    216   1458 378291.     259.       258.    10.3    499.
19 331           1     96    147  52838.     359.       368.   112.     496.
20 331           2     96    153  54444.     356.       365.   126.     498.
21 331           3     96    145  52302.     361.       383.   125.     498.
22 332           1    153    490 164521.     336.       368.    19.7    499.
23 332           2    153    493 164907.     334.       364.    15.1    500.
24 332           3    153    496 167105.     337.       364.    13.4    499.
25 333           1    300   1827 566342.     310.       331.    10.9    500.
26 333           2    299   1738 545602.     314.       338.    10.7    500.
27 333           3    299   1751 553628.     316.       341.    10.7    500.
```